# Using awk command in bash to extract a single field from a record

Tags: linux, bash

I want to use awk to extract a single field from a list of records. For example,

```
Assignment1:/home/dir/:Admin:08-07-12
Assignment2:/home/dir/:Paul:09-22-13
```

I want to extract the 1st field from the second line, or the third field from the first line. Any ideas?

Comment: Idea: Google "awk tutorial" and try some of the introductory examples. Downvoted for "this question doesn't show any research effort".

Comment: `awk -F: '{ print $1,$3 }' file`

Comment: This prints columns one and three, I want to print for example, line 1 column 2. Output would be only /home/dir/

Comment: this is not with columns but it can be give u the same result `cat file | cut -d : -f2 | sed -n '1p'` concatenate the file then `cut` words which located between delimiter `:` then print first line with `sed -n '1p'` and if you want to print second one `sed -n '2p'`

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F: 'NR == 2 { print $1 }'
awk -F: 'NR == 1 { print $3 }'
```

For the given line number, print the specified field.

#### It doesn't work

> My apologies, I am using the Bourne shell and this does not work.

As noted in the comment, I don't believe that the Bourne shell has anything directly to do with the problem.  (If `$IFS` is set to something odd, or some other peculiar setup applies, maybe that has an effect.  But in a normal Bourne shell, there should be no problem.)

Here's what I get on my machine (an Ubuntu 14.04 derivative, but I'm confident I'd get the same result on Mac OS X 10.10.3, and pretty much any other Unix-like system, too).  This is using Bash, but I don't think that's a factor — I'll go out on a limb and say that Korn shell, Zsh, Dash, and Heirloom Shell would all work the same on this; heck, it should work in the C shell family of shells too since there's nothing special about the notations used).  It is using GNU `awk` too, but I don't think that's a factor either.

```
$ cat data
Assignment1:/home/dir/:Admin:08-07-12
Assignment2:/home/dir/:Paul:09-22-13
$ awk -F: 'NR == 2 { print $1 }' data
Assignment2
$ awk -F: 'NR == 1 { print $3 }' data
Admin
$
```

The output looks like record 2, field 1 and record 1, field 3 to me.  Please find a way to demonstrate what you're doing and the result you get — probably, add something to the question.  We can clean it up later when we've worked out what's going wrong with your setup.  Please identify your platform reasonably clearly, too.

Comment: My apologies, I am using the Bourne shell and this does not work.

Comment: The code shown would work fine in Bourne shell.  There's nothing Bash-specific about it.  I find it hard to believe it wouldn't work in any version of `awk`, too.  Do you get an error message -- and if so, what?  If no error message, how do you know it isn't working?  What are you supplying as input?  Did you supply the filename?  Are you using single quotes (not double quote, back-quotes, Unicode special quotes, etc)?

Comment: No error. It just prints the first column, whatever is in the { print $1 } statement. I am using single-quotes, my script is your post verbatim. I am reading in a file as well, but that shouldn't matter should it?

Comment: Please see my follow-up in my answer.  Please show your results in a similar manner in your question -- we can remove them later.  I've checked the Unix 7th Edition manual for `awk` and I'm confident that the code shown would work with that, too -- it only relies on basic core features of `awk` present since the first (documented) version of `awk`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use 'cut' from bash like so

```
cut -d ":" -f "1,3" < asdf
Assignment1:Admin
Assignment2:Paul
```

Comment: That seems to be extracting field 3 from both lines, not from a specific line.